# annoying CTRL+F# instead of CTRL+ALT+F# Virtual Terminal Switching on Fedora 33 with sway wayland and gdm

Tags: fedora, tty, wayland, gdm, sway

I have the annoying problem that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> is switching to a Virtual Terminal. This should normally be done with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> but for some reason it is also triggered by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>.
I actually have an almost fresh Fedora 33 installation on a Lenovo laptop with sway and wayland.

I tried removing all Console_* bindings with something like:

```
sudo dumpkeys | grep -vE 'Console_5[^0-9]'  | sudo loadkeys
```

but it does not have an effect in sway/wayland.

I also tried `srvkeys:none`

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant dvorak-alt-intl -option srvkeys:none
```

but it has no effect either.

It doesn't matter if I start sway from gdm or from the shell. (however using a gnome session all is fine - i.e. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> does not switch to a virtual console)

I have no further ideas where and what to look for.
I have also filed an issue at https://github.com/swaywm/sway/issues/5885

Comment: What codes do you get using `xev` (both options)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solves the problem for me was to add the `srvrkeys:none` to the sway config like this:

```
input 'type:keyboard' {
  xkb_options 'srvkeys:none'
}
```

**N.B.** - it looks like using `grp:alts_toggle` somehow provokes the above issue, so instead of

```
input 'type:keyboard' {
  xkb_options 'srvkeys:none,grp:alts_toggle'
}
```

you might have to use a different binding for switching the layouts, i.e. `grp:shifts_toggle`:

```
input 'type:keyboard' {
  xkb_options 'srvkeys:none,grp:shifts_toggle'
}
```